# Artificial Neural Network with large inputs & outputs

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I've been following Dave Miller's ANN C++ Tutorial, and I've been having some problems getting it to function as expected.

You can view the code I'm working with [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0By5Pm7cPO56LTGFpMFBEbDNmTlU&usp=sharing). It's an XCode project, but includes the main.cpp and data set file.

Previously, this program would only gives outputs between -1 and 1, I'm presuming due to the use of the tanh function. I've manipulated the data inputs so I can input my data that is much larger and have valid outputs. I've simply done this by multiplying the input values by 0.0001, and multiplying the output values by 10000.

The training data I'm using is the included CSV file. The last column is the expected output, the rest are inputs. Am I using the wrong mathematical function for these data?

Would you say that this is actually learning? This whole thing has stressed me out so much, I understand the theory behind ANN's but just can't implement from scratch for myself.

The net recent average error definitely gets smaller and smaller, which to me would say it is learning.

I'm sorry if I haven't explained myself very well, I'm very new to ANN's and this whole thing is very confusing to me. My university lecturers are useless when it comes to the practical side, they only teach us the theory of it.

I've been playing around with the eta and alpha values, along with the number of hidden layers.

Comment: You're going to have to include the relevant parts of the code in your question, since otherwise you risk having your question closed. Try to cut it down as much as possible.

Comment: Could you please advise on what parts might directly be relevant? I just included in the entire source as I was unsure of what might be constituted as helpful.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the input values and output values. What are the ranges? First of all you should normalize the inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You explained yourself quite well, if the net recent average is getting lower and lower it probably means that the network is actually learning, but here is my suggestion about how to be completely sure.

Take you CSV file and split it into 2 files one should be about 10% of the all data and the other all the remaining. 
You start with an untrained network and you run your 10% file trough the net and for each line you save the difference between actual output and expected result. 
Then you train the network only with the 90% of the CSV file you have and finally you re run trough the NET the first 10% file again and you compare the differences you had on the first run with the the latest ones.
You should find out that the new results are much closer to the expected values than the first time, and this would be the final proof that your network is learning. 
Does this make any sense ? if not please send share some code or send me a link to the exercise you are running and I will try to explain it in code.

Comment: Yes! What you explain here is called _Cross validation_. it is described in all good books of neural lets and parameter estimation.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense, I'll definitely split that up now and try it out! Thank you! I'll report back once I've done it.

Comment: I haven't looked at your data, but just in case it is ordered in some way, it's  good to randomly sample the 10% which makes it in for the training set.

Comment: Would it be even better if I had the program take in the entire data set, then randomly select data to train on? I can always manually sift through the output. It'd probably go through some multiple times then I'd presume.

Comment: I've now implemented this, so it can be cycled through my 600 training data at random, as many times as you like. However it seems like after ~1,300 passes it actually gets worse at predicting it, is this normal? Also my code has always been linked in my post in the second paragraph :)

Comment: Right now I do not have my mac with me to try your code, anyway in general, the first prediction you have on untrained data is totally random and your result should never be "averagely" worst than that; if that is what you actually see it means that your training somehow is going in the opposite direction. If instead you mean that during training your result improve and from a certain point they start getting worst and worst that is strange, what I expect from a network is that results improve for a while and from a certain point they tend to remain quite stable.